# Converting 12.41 to 0000001241 in excel

Tags: excel

Basically what the title says. I need to convert cells with dollar values into a 10-digit format that will be a feed into a database program.

So, is there a way to custom format a cell so that I can point it towards a cell with $12.41 (for example), and have it automatically convert to 0000001241?

I already figured out how to get a cell to covert into 10 digit format, but for some reason it ignores the numbers after the period (the 41 cents).

Comment: Well, that must be because 12.41 and 1241 are not the same number. You can format 12.41 to 012.41, 12.410000, 12.4, 12... those are all different representations of the same number. 1241 is not. I'd create a formula to multiply all your numbers by 100, and then apply the format to the result instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(100*A1,".",""),"0000000000")
```